# friendship/follower functionality in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Any one have implemented a way manage to user friends(friendship in two way) and followers in database.

means what I want to achieve:
1) user1 send a connection request to user2.
2) then user2 accept user1 as friend or follower or reject it.
3) if user2 accept user1 as friend then this friendship is two way friendship.

what I am thinking to handle this:
1) I'll create a friendship table. 
2) relationship column that maintain a user is follower/friend.
3) if user is friend then I'll create two entry to maintain friends relationship from both end.

Could you please suggest me best approach(gems/plugin) to handle this case.

Comment: Your approach looks fine. You should implement it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create friendship with following fields

```
1] user_id
2] friend_id 
3] status
```

At first when user send a request for friendship `status` must be `Pending` and when friend `accept/reject` the request it should be change to the `Accepted/Rejected`

Answer (score 0):

You can create a table with columns - USER_A, USER_B, RELATION. Now, you can create a constant or enums to define the relation between USER_A and USER_B. For e.g. 0 represents no relation, 1 represents USER_A -> USER_B ( User A follows User B ), 2 represents USER_B -> USER_A ( User B follows User A ), and 3 presents USER_A <-> USER_B ( that means both way. )
You can then update the same row if you don't require history otherwise you can add one more row as the relation changes.
Hope that works!

Answer (score 0):

You can check out [socialization](https://github.com/cmer/socialization) gem that provide likes, following and mentions to your ActiveRecord models.